# Prolog clpfd :: operator expected

Tags: prolog, clpfd

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

I just wanted to test out the constrained logic programming library (clpfd) for Prolog. 
So I am including the library by calling

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Then I want to do sth like the following.

```
[X,Y] :: [1..2], X #\= Y, X+Y #\= 3.
```

But I always get the answer that

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: [X,Y]
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  :: [1..2], X #\= Y, X+Y #\= 3 .
```

---

The same happens when executing the following example

```
? member(X,[42,1,17]), [X,Y] :: [0..20].

ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: member(X,[42,1,17]), [X,Y]
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  :: [0..20] .
```

Seems like Prolog does not recognise the :: operator properly.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: What Prolog are you using and what do you think the `::` operator is?

Comment: Both B-Prolog and ECLiPSe define a `::/2` operator for constraints. Both provide alternatives to it (`in/2` in the case of B-Prolog and `in_set_range/2` in the case of ECLiPSe).

Comment: The ::/2 syntax originates from the very first finite-domain CLP system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHIP_(programming_language), and is used in CLP(FD) implementations such as ECLiPSe's library(ic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no `(::)/2` predicate in the `clpfd` library. You are probably looking for the [**`ins/2`**](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=ins/2) predicate. For example:

```
?- [X,Y] ins 1..2, X #\= Y, X+Y #\= 3, label([X,Y]).
false.

?- [X,Y] ins 1..3, X #\= Y, X+Y #\= 3, label([X,Y]).
X = 1,
Y = 3 ;
X = 2,
Y = 3 ;
X = 3,
Y = 1 .
```

So if `X` and `Y` are in `1..2`, then there is no solution, since your first constraint says `X` should be different from `Y`, and the second constraint says that `X + Y` should be different from `3`.

In case we add `3` to the result, then there are solutions.

We can here use `ins/2` to filter as well:

```
?- member(X,[42,1,17]), [X,Y] ins 0..20.
X = 1,
Y in 0..20 ;
X = 17,
Y in 0..20.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are absolutely right. The weird thing was that this code was given to us by our professor so I expected the code to work but it seems that the code is outdated